# Toggle display / hide and Button to new page to show certain field of record in php

Tags: javascript, php, sql

I wish not to display all fields of records from query. I wish either a button in the query records to a new page to display the field. And a button toggle display a field.

I can't figure out the action code for the button to new page. And I can only toggle display / hide only the first record.

After reading some answers here, I think the problem should be the id of the record, which my code dont assign a unique id for each record. Seems I can't figure how to solve it. As for the button to new page, I stuck.

Below is to button to new page to `echo $row['contact']`

```
    <?php

    $data = mysqli_query($conn, $query) or die('error');
if(mysqli_num_rows($data) > 0){
while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($data)){

    $status = $row['status'];
    $area = $row['area'];
$address = $row['address'];
?>

<tr>
<td><form method="post" name="dataid" value="'.$row->new_id.'"><input 
    type="submit" name="submit1"></form></td>
<td><?php echo $row['status'];?></td>
<td><?php echo $row['area'];?></td>
<td><?php echo $row['address'];?></td>
</tr>
```

Below is meant to toggle display / hide `$row['contact']`

```
     <?php 
     $data = mysqli_query($conn, $query) or die('error');
 if(mysqli_num_rows($data) > 0){
 while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($data)){

$status = $row['status'];
    $area = $row['area'];
$address = $row['address'];
?>

    <tr>
<td>
<div id=1 onclick="document.getElementById('body_1').style.display= 
    (document.getElementById('body_1').style.display=='none'? 'block':'none')">Click</div>
<div id="body_1" style="display:none; border:2px solid green;"><?php echo $row['contact'];?></div>

    </td>
<td><?php echo $row['status'];?></td>
    <td><?php echo $row['area'];?></td>
<td><?php echo $row['address'];?></td>                                   
    </tr>
```

My button not working yet. And only toggle display / hide only the first record

I try this code to button / link to certain field of my record :

a href="detail.php?new_id=">Click

In detail.php :

```
     <?php
     if(isset($_GET['new_id']) && $_GET['new_id'] !== ''){
     $new_id = $_GET['new_id'];
     echo $new_id;
     echo $contact;
     } else {
     echo "failed";
     }
     ?>                                                                                                                                                                    
                                                                                                                             Result : I can display the $new_id, but unable to display $contact
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are two reasons why this code isn't working for multiple `div` elements with the `id` "body_1":

- An `id` in HTML is unique. Which means, you may only have **one** HTML element with that specific `id` in your `DOM`.
- The JS selector `getElementById()` will only return one element with the specified `id`. That is because an `id` is supposed to be unique.

If your `$row` array contains an id element (if you have a column in your database table with an unique identifier (id)) you could use this value to give your `HTML elements` its unique ID.

I am personally not a huge fan of using in-line JS code like this. I prefer to keep it in a separate `.js` file for readability and caching purposes, but the following code may help you out if your rows contain an id which can be accessed by `$row['id']`:

```
$data = mysqli_query($conn, $query) or die('error');

if (mysqli_num_rows($data) > 0) {
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($data)) {

$status = $row['status'];
$area = $row['area'];
$address = $row['address'];
?>

<tr>
    <td>
        <div onclick="document.getElementById('<?= 'body_' . $row['id'] ?>').style.display= 
    (document.getElementById('<?= 'body_' . $row['id'] ?>').style.display==='none'? 'block':'none')">Click
        </div>
        <div id="<?= 'body_' . $row['id'] ?>" style="display:none; border:2px solid green;"><?php echo $row['contact']; ?></div>

    </td>
    <td><?php echo $row['status']; ?></td>
    <td><?php echo $row['area']; ?></td>
    <td><?php echo $row['address']; ?></td>
</tr>
```

`<?= 'text' ?>` is a shorthand for `<?php echo 'text' ?>`. I have also used the the triple equals `===` instead of `==` to compare if the style property `display` has 'none' as its value because of [Test Equality](https://codeburst.io/javascript-showdown-vs-7be792be15b5)

Comment: yes it works now...wow great. I was die trying to figure how to make correct coding for unique id until your clue. really appreciate it.

Comment: How about my button to open new page to display the field ?

Comment: I try add in <td><a href="detail.php?new_id=<?php echo $new_id; ?>">Click</a></td>

Comment: detail.php is                                                                                                           
     <?php
     if(isset($_GET['new_id']) && $_GET['new_id'] !== ''){
     $new_id = $_GET['new_id'];
     echo $new_id;
     echo $contact;
     } else {
     echo "failed";
     }
     ?>

Comment: I can echo $new_id in new page, but echo $contact not working

Comment: In this case you would also have to add the value of `$contact` as a parameter in your `anchor` element (`<a></a>`). You can then retrieve it on the same way as 'new_id' using the `$_GET` superglobal.

Comment: Yes, I did use $contact as a parameter to retrieve contact and it worked. But only the contact displayed, it is possible to echo other field as well ?

Comment: If you add all these fields as a parameter in the destination your `anchor` element, then yes. Just like you added `$new_id` and `$contact` as a parameter.

Comment: <td><a href="detail1.php?contact_person=<?php echo $contact_person; ?>">Click</a></td>                                                                                                                            
                                                                                                                           Is it possible to add more than 1 field in above (<a></a>) element ?

Comment: <td><a href="detail1.php?contact_person=<?php echo $contact_person; ?><?php echo $new_id; ?>">Click</a></td>                                                                                                     
                                                                                                                                 
I simply add like above and it return both contact and id in detail1.php, is not beautiful but at least a solution for me so far.

Comment: I just discovered that this GET only pass about 60 character to my detail1.php, some of my data has more than 200 character....I dont see any code setting limiting it. Anything to do to break the limit ?

Comment: The superglobal `$_GET` has the char limit which you have set in your `php.ini`. The best practice, however, would be to reference to the ID of your row. Based on that you'll perform a new SQL `query` with an ID filter. So, you'll add the id as a parameter in your URL. In your other `php` file you'll perform a `query` with a [WHERE clause](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_where.asp). Also, for more `parameters` in your URL, read the following:  [Query strings explained](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Query_string)

Comment: Noted. Thank you